# MKLocalSearchCompleter not working with street numbers

Tags: swift, mapkit

I am using `MKLocalSearchCompleter` to search addresses, however it is not showing me the exact locations. For example you can take address like J.Kunderi 24, Tallinn. It does not show nothing but if you search J.kunderi, it gives results. In conclusion, the query is not working when using exact `queryFragment`.

This is what I do:

```
var matchingItems: [MKLocalSearchCompletion] = []

    //create a completer
    lazy var searchCompleter: MKLocalSearchCompleter = {
        let sC = MKLocalSearchCompleter()
        sC.delegate = self
        return sC
    }()

extension LocationPickerViewController: UISearchBarDelegate{

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if !searchText.isEmpty {
            searchCompleter.filterType = .locationsAndQueries
            searchCompleter.queryFragment = searchText
        }
    }

}

extension LocationPickerViewController: MKLocalSearchCompleterDelegate{
    func completerDidUpdateResults(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter) {
        self.matchingItems = completer.results
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.locationTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?